# Express Server Proxy Multiple Applications

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to write a reverse proxy to multiple node applications.  When do something like this:

```
app.use('/', proxy('http://localhost:5010/'));
app.listen(8000, (err) => {
if (err) {
    return console.error('Application failed to start:', err);
}
    console.log('Application listening on port', 8000);
});
```

It works as expected.  But when I do something like

```
app.use('/', proxy('http://localhost:5010/'));
app.use('/config', proxy('http://localhost:5020/config'));
app.listen(8000, (err) => {
if (err) {
    return console.error('Application failed to start:', err);
}
    console.log('Application listening on port', 8000);
});
```

My requests to http://localhost:8000/config get routed to localhost:5010

If I only do just the proxy to `/config` it will route properly.  Its something about when I do multiple proxies.

I am using express and express-http-proxy for this.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express middlewares gets executed in the sequence. So your first line

```
app.use('/', proxy('http://localhost:5010/'));
```

is true for the `/` and `/config` and all the routes. So if you want to do something different for some routes put that on the top

```
app.use('/config', proxy('http://localhost:5020/config'));
app.use('/', proxy('http://localhost:5010/'));
```

So now your first line will be valid for only `/config` path and all other routers will move forward  to secod handler.